# Cannot set correct year by using Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have the following code and want to set cal to `01.01.2016`.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2016, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

But it always return `01.01.2015`. I tried to set year to `2017`, it outputs `2016`. For `2015`, `2014` and `2018`, it works correctly.

Comment: year should have small 'y': yyyy

Comment: My fault. Thank you. Have not noticed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The year in format must be an lower case `y`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Upper case `Y` is for Week year.

For more details see the [java doc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)